# Use animations to show color sequence (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewanimation

Hi I'm new to Swift and I want to create a color memory game for IPhone where your app gives you a sequence of colors and you have to repeat it by pressing the right buttons. The sequence becomes longer and longer everytime you pressed the right buttons of the previous sequence.

I want the app to show which button is pressed by using an animation on the button. The sequence will make the buttons flash and then the user can recreate the sequence.

I have a method that does the flash(), which is a part of a class which is an extension of UIButton

```
 func flash() {

    let flash = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    flash.duration = 0.2
    flash.fromValue = 1
    flash.toValue = 0.1
    flash.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    flash.autoreverses = true
    flash.repeatCount = 1

    layer.add(flash, forKey: nil)
}
```

When I perform this method on a sequence of buttons it flashes all of the buttons, written in the sequence, at the same time. This is not the way I want it of course, I want the buttons to flash one after another.

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

var colorPattern = [Int]()

@IBOutlet weak var buttonGreen: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonRed: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonBlue: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var buttonYellow: UIButton!
var buttons = [UIButton]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    buttons = [buttonGreen, buttonRed, buttonBlue, buttonYellow]
    colorPattern = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func colorButtonTouched(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("button touched: ", sender.titleLabel!.text!)
    //sender.flash()
    doPattern()
}


func doPattern() {
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.calculationModeCubic], animations: {
        // Add animations
        for index in self.colorPattern{
            print(index);
            UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1, animations: self.buttons[index].flash)
        }
    }, completion:{ _ in
        print("I'm done!")
    })
}
}
```

When I perform this code button 1, 2 and 3 flash at the same time. Is there a way to fix this? or are animations just not the right way to go with looping sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var currentButtonIndex = 0
func doPattern()
{
    let currentButton = self.buttons[self.currentButtonIndex]
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse], animations: {
        currentButton.alpha = 0
    }) { (complete) in
        currentButton.alpha = 1
        if self.currentButtonIndex == self.buttons.count - 1
        {
            self.currentButtonIndex = 0
            return
        }

        self.currentButtonIndex += 1
        self.doPattern()
    }
}
```

Comment: I made some adjustments to this solution and it works perfectly! 
`let currentButton = self.buttons[self.colorPattern[self.currentButtonIndex]]`

Comment: and also changed the if statement to `if self.currentButtonIndex == self.colorPattern.count - 1
            {
                self.currentButtonIndex = 0
                return
            }`

Comment: What is the main difference between my solution and yours?

Comment: The main difference is that I used a UIView animation instead of a Core Animation.